# Unable to use perforce tickets set by jenkins to automate perforce login

Tags: jenkins, perforce

Trying to automate login in jenkins as passsword expires after few days. Jenkins sets $P4_TICKET environment variable. I am trying to use this so that user need not to relogin again to enter his password.

```
echo $P4_TICKET > $P4TICKETS

Actual result : Unexpected exception while loading target: Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.
```

Expected : perforce tickets should be used from jenkins . Here i am trying to copy to my environment variable $P4TICKETS

Answer (score 0):

1. Is your `$P4TICKETS` variable actually set to the name of a file?
2. Does the `$P4_TICKET` value set by Jenkins actually match the expected format of that file?

The `$P4TICKETS` value isn't necessarily set within any given client environment, so that's the first thing to check.  The client will assume a default tickets file name of `~/.p4tickets`, but the shell doesn't know that it should use that value for the environment variable `$P4TICKETS`.

The `.p4tickets` file contains potentially multiple tickets indexed by user/port; if Jenkins's `$P4_TICKET` value is just the ticket (like you'd get from `p4 login -p`), it won't be recognized if you just dump it into a ticket file (because the client won't know what connection it goes with).

Answer (score 0):

P4_TICKET is just the ticket value for the credential that your jenkins' job has.

> Here i am trying to copy to my environment variable $P4TICKETS

As Sam mentioned, your tickets file ($P4TICKETS) needs the server's addr and user along with the ticket value.   The "p4 plugin" does not expose the server's addr so you will not be able to write out a valid row within your tickets file.

As to your question, "Trying to automate login in jenkins", I don't understand what you need to do.   A "Perforce password credential" will login for you.  Please give more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Sam Stafford and J Brown. You both were right. P4TICKETS was unable to find just by ticket hash. I had to include P4PORT, P4USER and Tickets to ~/.p4tickets and then enable "ALL HOSTS" under users credentials with whom i was logging into to jenkins. This made me to login and continue

Thank you:)